# Default to home route if no param passed

Tags: javascript, react-router

I have some basic routes setup on my index.js

```
import { Router,
  Route,
  hashHistory,
  Link } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
               <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={Users} />
                <Route path="/posts/:id" component={Posts} />
              </Router>
            ,
document.getElementById('root')
```

Can I redirect the to the home route if no parameter is passed to the posts route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`<Redirect>`](http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Redirect.html) for that route:

```
<Router history={ hashHistory }>
  <Route path="/" component={ Users } />
  <Redirect from="/posts/" to="/" />
  <Route path="/posts/:id" component={ Posts } />
</Router>
```

Comment: I think you should leave Redirect after the route, at least that way worked for me ....

Comment: @DavidNoreña It shouldn't matter, they are evaluated in order and `/posts/` wont match `/posts/:id`.

Comment: @Jivings you need to add exact on <Redirect /> else it will redirect path="/posts/:id" to , with exact only =/posts/ will be redirect to ="/"

Comment: this won' t work if somehow we use `history.push('posts/:id')`